# "Regardless of" meaning and using in sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> "Regardless of sunny weather, they went for playing football."
>   "Regardless of social networking, many people getting famous personality"

Could you tell whether above two sentences are correct?

Comment: "many people getting famous personality" is ungrammatical.  If these people are _getting famous_  then they are _becoming famous personalities_ (i.e., _celebrities_). They are not _getting_ their personality; they already have it. Or perhaps you meant they are "getting famous personally?"

Answer (score 2):

*Regardless* of should indicate that what follows is surprising in some way, or that what preceded didn't matter. A good synonym would be *despite*.

For example, I might say:

> Regardless of the *rainy* weather, they went *to play* football.

That's another way of saying:

> Even though it was raining, they went to play football.

Your initial example talked about sunny whether:

> Regardless of sunny weather, they went for playing football.

Sunny weather sounds ideal for playing football! So *regardless* doesn't sound quite right there.

As for the order, you could also say the sentence like this:

> They played football, regardless of the bad weather.

Both forms are used.

Answer (score 0):

They are ***quite okay***. The word 'regardless' can be used that way. **And,** a sentence **can** begin with this word.

Other examples from [YourDictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/regardless):

> Regardless of whether he 's the six billionth baby or not, I 'm a happy mother. 
>  Regardless of the artist, all the subjects seem to end up looking stern. 
> Regardless of what they think of his politics, most Jewish activists likely would welcome Soros ' participation in the world of Jewish philanthropy.

And there are many more.

Comment: Orderwise, they are okay, but I still think the O.P. is missing something. I wouldn't play football _regardless of_ the sunny weather – though I might play football _because of_ the sunny weather.